# How to extract values from a vector with a specified step in DolphinDB?

Tags: python, dolphindb

I have two quetions:

Does DolphinDB offer any functions or methods to generate an
arithmetic sequence of natural numbers or dates?

I also want to extract values from a vector with a specified step. Below is an example of how this is done in Python:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
print(x[::3])
//output: [1, 4, 7]
```

How can I achieve this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, try the following method:

```
2020.01.01 + 12*0..10
```

For your second question, you can first calculate the indices based on the desired step before extracting the values:

```
a = 1..10
a[3*til ceil(a.count()\3)]

[1,4,7,10]
```